# How to simplify this complex fraction? $\frac{a^{-2}-b^{-1}} {10a^{-1}+4b^{-2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\dfrac{a^{-2}-b^{-1}} {10a^{-1}+4b^{-2}}$$
I am having trouble with simplifying this expression. I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use the fact that

$$a^{-b} = \frac 1{a^b}$$

It follows that, $$\frac 1{a^{-b}} = \frac1{\frac 1{a^b}} = a^b$$

So $$\dfrac{a^{-2}-b^{-1}}{10a^{-1}+4b^{-2}}= \dfrac{\frac 1{a^2} - \frac 1b}{\frac{10}{a} + \frac{4}{b^2}}$$

You can clear the "fractions in the fraction" by multiplying both numerator and denominator by $a^2 b^2$, and take it from there.